# call webservice using httppost method in android with parameter

Tags: android, web-services, http-post

I want to call a `Web-service` using a `Http-post` method.I want to call this URL:

http://serverurl/webservice/login.php?message=[{"username":"durgesh","password":"pass123"}]

how to call this and how to pass parameter?

Comment: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

urlpath="http://192.168.1.158/VisionEPODWebService/VisionEPOD.apk";
            String ApkName = "VisionEPOD.apk";

```
        URL url = new URL(urlpath.toString()); 
        // Your given URL.             
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");           
        c.setDoOutput(true);            
        c.connect();
```